# Keyboard Matrix code not returning correct column number when a button is pressed

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide

```
int ColumnPins = 4;  //How many column pins
int RowPins = 5; //How many row pins
int Columns[] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; //Column pinNumbers
int Rows[] = {4, 6, 7, 8, 9}; //Row pinNumbers

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  for (int counter = 0; counter < ColumnPins; counter++) 
  { //set all the columns to output
    pinMode(Columns[counter], OUTPUT);
  }
  for (int counter = 0; counter < RowPins; counter++) 
   { //set all rows to input
    pinMode(Rows[counter],INPUT_PULLDOWN);
    }
}

void loop()
{
  for (int ColumnIndex = 0; ColumnIndex < ColumnPins; ColumnIndex++) //sets column pins to high 1 by 1 
  {
    digitalWrite(Columns[ColumnIndex], HIGH);
    RowScan(ColumnIndex); //calls function rowscan checks whether and row is HIGH 
    digitalWrite(Columns[ColumnIndex], LOW);
  }
}

void RowScan(int ColumnIndex) //Scans each rowpin and checks whether any reads high
{
  for (int RowIndex = 0; RowIndex < RowPins; RowIndex++) 
    {
      if (digitalRead(Rows[RowIndex]) == HIGH) //if Rows at rowindex is high
      {
        for (int blinks = 0; blinks <= RowIndex; blinks++)
        { //Outputs # of blinks based on which row HIGH was read
          // print index
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //LEDPIN high
          delay(250);
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
          delay(500);
        }
        for (int blinks = 0; blinks <= ColumnIndex; blinks++)
        { //Outputs # of blinks based on which row HIGH was read
          // print index
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH); //LEDPIN high
          delay(100);
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
          delay(100);
        }
      }
    else if (digitalRead(Rows[RowIndex]) == LOW) //Rows at index o is LOW
    {
      digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

C++ Arduino IDE 
Column is returning a random value from 0-3 based on the time it is pressed where it should just return the column that is set to high when a row reads high.
Not sure how to fix pretty sure there is an issue with the first for loop in void loop().

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best if we print the indices to the Serial Monitor to see if it's working. Try these codes below.

```
int totalCols = 4;
int totalRows = 5;

// exclude pins 0 and 1 since these are used for Serial communication
int keyCols[] = { 2, 4, 5,  6     }; 
int keyRows[] = { 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600); // begin Serial Communication at 9600 baudrate
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++)
        pinMode(keyCols[i], OUTPUT);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++) 
        pinMode(keyRows[i], INPUT); // you can use INPUT instead
}

void loop() {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCols; i++) {
        digitalWrite(keyCols[i], HIGH);
        ScanActiveRows(i);
        digitalWrite(keyCols[i], LOW);
    }
}

void ScanActiveRows(int col) {
    delay(5); // wait for 5 milliseconds after setting column pin
    for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
        if (digitalRead(keyRows[row]) == HIGH) {

            // print column and row indices
            Serial.print("Column : ");
            Serial.println(col);
            Serial.print("Row : ");
            Serial.println(row);

        }
        else if (digitalRead(keyRows[row]) == LOW) {
            digitalWrite(13,LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

If the above code outputs the exact column and row, then the blink for-loop is the problem. I hope this helps. This is my first time answering. :)